# Wrapper to enclose several chapters in LaTeX

Tags: chapters, parts, report

If I have a document with the order of chapters as follows

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report} % 

... 

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{LiteratureReview}
\part{Wrapper part for chapters for case studies 1 and 2}
\chapter{CaseStudy_1}
\chapter{CaseStudy_2}    
\part{Wrapper part for chapters for case studies 3 and 4}
\chapter{CaseStudy_3}
\chapter{CaseStudy_4} 
\chapter{Conclusion}    
...
```

I want to have certain chapters wrapped into parts. This is the case using `\part` but unfortunately `\part` includes everything after it. So my Conclusion becomes part of my wrapper for chapters covering case studies 3 and 4.

Is it possible to end a part when defined so that chapters after it are not part (no pun intended) of it?

The following code demonstrates a simple version of the problem where the Conclusion is part of Part 2:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{Literature Review}
\part{Paradigm 1}
\chapter{CaseStudy 1}
\chapter{CaseStudy 2}
\part{Paradigm 2}
\chapter{CaseStudy 3}
\chapter{CaseStudy 4}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Can chapter numbers per part also be reset so that each starts at 1?

Thanks to the respondents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\part` does not wrap your chapters actually. What you probably mean is a clear (optical) distinction between the `\chapter{CaseStudy 4} and the following chapters. `\chapter{Appendix}` is not needed, as it suffices to say `\appendix` normally.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Names with `_` are problematic, they won't work

Comment: You should also think about the fact, that `part` does not reset the chapter counter...

Comment: I have removed the Appendix reference but I will upload an MWE shortly.

Comment: MWE appended to question.

Comment: `part` is a level higher than `chapter`. For example, a book has different `parts`, each `part` containing different `chapters`, each `chapter` containing different `sections` ... Are you looking for `sections`?

Comment: `\part` doesn't really 'enclose' anything: unlike the relationship between say `\chapter` and `\section` there is no 'this section is part of this chapter' thing going on in the numbering of parts. They are used for 'larger' subdivision of a work, and usually if you want say conclusions or references to show a different part to the rest you'd simply add `\part{Final considerations}` or something.

Comment: Try something like `\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}`.

Comment: I think, this question is in general too broad, as there are too many possible solutions.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{Literature Review}
\section{Paradigm 1}
\subsection{CaseStudy 1}
\subsection{CaseStudy 2}
\section{Paradigm 2}
\subsection{CaseStudy 3}
\subsection{CaseStudy 4}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the OP wants to stick to `\part` .... this answer provides a version with automatic resetting of chapter numbers for each part.

In my point of view, the structuring commands should be used differently, see another version below the `\part` solution.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report} % 

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}

\makeatother

\begin{document}%

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{LiteratureReview}
\part{Wrapper part for chapters for case studies 1 and 2}
\chapter{CaseStudy 1}
\chapter{CaseStudy 2}    
\part{Wrapper part for chapters for case studies 3 and 4}
\chapter{CaseStudy 3}
\chapter{CaseStudy 4} 

\part{Final Remarks}%
\chapter{Conclusion}
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixname}

\chapter{First Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second version, a personal approach

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report} % 


\begin{document}%

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{LiteratureReview}
\let\originalthesection\thesection
\chapter{Casestudies}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{C\arabic{section}}
\section{CaseStudy 1}
\section{CaseStudy 2}    
\section{CaseStudy 3}
\section{CaseStudy 4} 

\let\thesection\originalthesection%
\chapter{Conclusion}
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}

\chapter{First Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if necessary, I can always group the first three chapters into a Part called Preliminaries. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, one of the points of `\part` is that it _doesn't_ reset the numbering!

Comment: @MrMorgan: You could do that of course. I personally think that that `orphan` chapter (Conclusion) should be extended etc.

Comment: @JosephWright: I know... As I wrote -- if the OP wants to stick to `\parts`...

Answer (score 1):

Edit answering OPs further questions - even though there's an accepted answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\newcounter{rememberchapter}

\newcommand{\firstpart}[1]{%
\setcounter{rememberchapter}{\value{chapter}}
\part{#1}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
}

\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
\part{#1}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
}

\newcommand{\nopart}{%
\setcounter{chapter}{\value{rememberchapter}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{Literature Review}
\firstpart{Paradigm 1}
\chapter{CaseStudy 1}
remembering: \arabic{chapter} and \arabic{rememberchapter}
\chapter{CaseStudy 2}
\mypart{Paradigm 2}
\chapter{CaseStudy 3}
\chapter{CaseStudy 4}
\nopart
\chapter{Conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost perfect. But can the conclusion be numbered Chapter 4 following on from the chapters before Part 1? And what of the chapters in the parts being A, B instead of 1 and 2 etc?